# PHP - Função para remover caractere e concatenar strings (URL relativa para absoluta)

Tags: php, url, normalização

Boas pessoal!

Estou com um pequeno problema (problema por eu não trabalhar muito com php).

Estou usando um script atrelado ao phpbb que exibe os topicos de determinado fórum em uma página externa, mas o cms me retorna apenas a url relativa (o script está no root do site e o phpbb instalado em ./forum), com isso não consigo criar um rss por exemplo, que me exige a url absoluta.

O formato retornado pelo phpbb é `./forum/viewtopic.php?f=xx&t=xx`

O que eu preciso nem é algo tão profundo do phpbb, mas sim simplesmente uma forma de trasformar esse caminho relativo em um caminho absoluto, simplesmente retirar aquele primeiro ponto e adicionar por exemplo `http://exemplo.com` no lugar, ficando então `http://exemplo.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=xx&t=xx`.

Como eu poderia fazer uma função pra trabalhar isso usando o php (talvez uma função que use regex, eu não sei)?

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Cara, URL relativa nunca tem "." (pontos). Se é retornado "ponto" é porque é caminho físico, não URL.

Comment: Além do mais, isso depende muito. Você quer a partir de um dado script (rss.php, por exemplo) obter a URL absoluta do atual script em execução?

Comment: Não exatamente, felipsmartins. O caracter de ponto é usado para atribuir um diretório corrente ou o diretório de recuo no caso de dois pontos `../`. Pode ser usado em path físico do filesystem ou virtual (url). Não tem a ver com identificar se é relativo ou absoluto. Um path relativo ou absoluto pode conter recuos. Resumindo, o jeito certo de dizer é **normalizar url** ou "normalizar um path". Uma diferença sutil, porém significativa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, como foi comentado acima, o caminho que eu recebo é físico, e eu preciso transformar para uma URL absoluta.

Enfim, um usuário do stack internacional [me respondeu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35492691/4836556):

`$url = str_replace('./', 'http://example.com/', $url);`

Comment: O ./ não representa o diretório raíz.

Answer (score 0):

O termo apropriado é *canonicalizar* ou *normalizar* url

Exemplo de rotina para normalizar uma url:

```
function canonicalize_url($str)
{

    $protocol = '';

    if (strpos($str, 'http://') !== false) {
        $protocol = 'http://';
        $str = substr($str, 7);
    } else if (strpos($str, 'https://') !== false) {
        $protocol = 'https://';
        $str = substr($str, 8);     
    } else if (strpos($str, '//') === 0) {
        $protocol = '//';
        $str = substr($str, 2);     
    }

    if (strpos($str, '/..') !== false) {
        $str = explode('/', $str);
        $first = $str[0];
        $keys = array_keys($str, '..');

        foreach ($keys as $k => $v) {
            array_splice($str, $v - ($k * 2 + 1), 2);
        }

        if (empty($str)) {
            $str = array($first);
        } else {
            reset($str);
            if ($first != $str[0]) {
                array_unshift($str, $first);
            }
        }

        return $protocol.str_replace('./', '', implode('/', $str));
    }

    return $protocol.str_replace('./', '', $str);

}

// testando url absoluta (http, https e protocolo genérico //)
$url = 'https://www.foo.bar/folder1/../folder2/bar/../../..';
$url = 'http://www.foo.bar/folder1/../folder2/bar/../';
$url = '//www.example.com/folder1/../folder2/bar/../../..';

// testando exceço de recuos. A função detecta e impede o recuo além da raiz da url (virtualmente).
$url = '//www.example.com/folder1/../folder2/bar/../../../../../../../../';

// testando url relativa
$url = './folder1/folder2/';
echo canonicalize_url($url); //http://www.example.com/else
```

*A função acima não identifica barras duplicadas, por exemplo* `http://www.foo.bar/..////pasta`